# How to make an async task call in .onDelete?

Tags: listview, mvvm, swiftui

I have a List with User type items, I have implemented .onDelete:

```
List {
            //foreach with id
            ForEach(usersListVM.users, id: \.id) { user in
                ResponsiveView { prop in
                    UserCell(prop: prop, user: user)
                }
            }
                    .onDelete { index in
                        usersListVM.deleteUser(id: usersListVM.users[index.first!].id!)
                    }
        }
```

and the delete fucntion by an Api is async/await:

```
func deleteUser(id: Int) async {
        try await userApi.deleteUser(id: id)
}
```

but I can not implement this code because I have this error:
[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

When calling an async function inside a function that does not support concurrency, you must wrap the call inside a `Task` block.

```
.onDelete { index in
    Task {
        await usersListVM.deleteUser(id: usersListVM.users[index.first!].id!)
    }
}
```

Comment: now I receive another error : "Result of call to 'task(priority:_:)' is unused" and the app skips the task. I am debbuging and it does not enter inside the task.

Comment: I recommend adding a function that calls `usersListVM.deleteUser` and calling that function in the `.onDelete` block to avoid making an async call inside `.onDelete`.

Comment: I think it´s the same because .onDelete continue requesting a task.

Comment: Your real question is how to make an async call in .onDelete, not how to remove a list item from a server. Edit your question to reflect the real question. Change the question title if you can. Add the information about the async call not being made when wrapped in a `Task` block. You have a good question, but I don't have an answer. Maybe someone else will have an answer if you edit the question.